# What does this specific piece of code in Alexa do?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, this, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I've seen the following code in Alexa:

```
var Response = function (context, session) { this._context = context; this._session = session; };
```

I'm unsure what it is trying to so, specifically this part:

`_context.`

Thanks

Comment: it's a class constructor that initialized the object properties.

Comment: You should read a tutorial on object-oriented programming in Javascript.

Comment: Looks just like an ordinary constructor to me, what;s the problem?
Also, worst ever question title- how is that going to help others in the future with the same problem. Please update it

Answer (score 2):

It's a class constructor that initializes the properties of the new object from its parameters.

```js
var Response = function(context, session) {
  this._context = context;
  this._session = session;
};

var r = new Response("a context", "session 1");
console.log(r);
```